# Using dd to test Write speeds

Tags: dd, io

I'm trying to check the write speed of different devices that I have using the following:

```
dd bs=1M count=256 if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/device oflag=dsync
```

I want an accurate reading of write speed and I was wondering if I should have any considerable speed difference by using a file that isn't just zeros, or if using /dev/zero is a reasonable way to test write speed.

Comment: Use `/dev/urandom`, if you want continuous, random data.

Comment: Muru,  do you think time command would do the trick here ? Then the output could be used to calculate the speed,  right?

Comment: @muru Random generator is too slow and does not allow to check write speed. `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1M count=100` returns ~`19 MB/s`. All modern devices are much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a test of `/dev/zero`'s throughput on my system:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1000000
1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
1048576000000 bytes (1,0 TB) copied, 65,2162 s, 16,1 GB/s
```

There's no other bottleneck than the CPU's cache speed here. That means that in my system `/dev/zero` can generate up to `16,1 GB/s` of zeros, so it **definetly** should be fast enough for your purpose.

Comment: I doubt the speed of getting zeros from `/dev/zero` was ever in question. It will return zeros as quickly as the kernel can process requests.

Comment: @muru "I was wondering [...] if using /dev/zero is a reasonable way to test write speed", so I think that's exactly what he wants to know

Comment: If you want to just measure the speed at which `zero` can throw `zeros`, use `/dev/null` for `of`. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1000`

Comment: @muru I tested `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1000000`, it ran at `16,1 GB/s`. Shouldn't it cap on memory's bandwidth either?

Comment: should it? This is pure CPU. Both are kernel services, one throwing zeros as fast as it can, and the other discarding everything it gets as fast as it can.

Comment: @muru I guess it is, altough I don't understand why with a block size of `10MB+` (exceeding the CPU's cache) and `iflag=fullblock` it's still `4,7 GB/s`, doesn't it rely on RAM ever?

Comment: For each block, perhaps.

Comment: @muru Sorry I'm really tired and I'm not getting it, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Pick a humongous block size (say 10G) and watch the virtual memory usage of `dd`.

Comment: @muru Worse than before, I need some rest. Anyway it didn't let me pick up anything larger than physical memory, and at `3GB` I was almost crashing, it did always fill up as much memory as the block size

Comment: I was having problems phrasing my question I guess, I just want to know if  using /dev/zeros to test write speed will give a Realistic write speed. Or if it will be higher/lower than normal due to the nature of the file.

Comment: @BrianSizemore Yes it is, the test's purpose is to show that e.g. while using the memory as the target (which is *way* faster than a regular drive), `/dev/zero` can keep up to generate up to `1,4 GB/s` of zeros, so it definetly won't bottleneck. On the other hand, say to use a source file on a HDD to benchmark a SSD is not enough, because the test would be bottlenecked from the low HDD read spead. Anyway I updated using muru's suggestion, which shows that the cap is even higher than `1,4 GB/s`

Comment: Thank you. That makes vastly more sense once you've explained it that way. So does /dev/urandom just throw random bits instead of zeros?

Comment: @BrianSizemore Yes exactly, and it's *not* good for testing because it's *painfully* slow, it will *definetly* bottleneck the read speed

Answer (score 4):

Not always.  I was recently testing a disk in exactly the same way and `/dev/zero` tricked me into thinking I had the performance I needed because the external disk was using *NTFS disk compression*.  At first I tried using `/dev/urandom` to fix this problem, but I discovered that tricked me into thinking that things were going too slowly.  If you want to do this without being tricked then you need to write a random file to a `tmpfs` location and copy *that* file to the destination disk.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/temp-random.img bs=1G count=1 iflag=fullblock oflag=dsync
dd if=/tmp/temp-random.img of=/path/to/device/temp-random.img bs=1G count=1 iflag=fullblock oflag=dsync
```

Please note that this assumes that `/tmp` is mounted as `tmpfs`, if that's not the case then you should mount a temporary filesystem and use that instead:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/tmp
sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/tmp/
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/tmp/temp-random.img bs=1G count=1 iflag=fullblock oflag=dsync
dd if=/mnt/tmp/temp-random.img of=/path/to/device/temp-random.img bs=1G count=1 iflag=fullblock oflag=dsync
sudo umount /mnt/tmp/
sudo rmdir /mnt/tmp
```

Also note that you need to make sure that your file is large enough to be bigger than the cache of the disk (set `count=N` much bigger than the cache size in GiB).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps /dev/zero isn't a *realistic* source; stable but not realistic. You'll get maybe the fastest rate, but IRL the information isn't usually that organized. In order to check this, run a couple of tests using /dev/zero and /dev/urandom and compare the rates. Another point you must take into account is the **bs** parameter. If you don't optimize this value, the precision will be poor once again. The optimal size depends on a number of factors (i.e. the SO, the architecture, some characteristics of the device you're writing on,...). I've just run this test against my SSD; just ten seconds of writing:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./output_file 
2968447+0 records in
2968447+0 records out
1519844864 bytes (1,5 GB, 1,4 GiB) copied, 8,52739 s, 178 MB/s

dd if=/dev/zero of=./output_file bs=4096
942211+0 records in
942211+0 records out
3859296256 bytes (3,9 GB, 3,6 GiB) copied, 17,3544 s, 222 MB/s
```

So, 4096 looks a good block size in my hardware but I needed to run a long battery of tests in order to determine it. And... the largest **bs**, the better?. Not always.

Comment: I found this jewel. Thanks, Danny Guinther. https://github.com/tdg5/blog/blob/master/_includes/scripts/dd_obs_test.sh